# How to Tell Outlook I want to Compose A New Email with PlainText Format

Tags: hyperlink, outlook, mailto

How to Tell Outlook I want to Compose A New Email with PlainText Format if I am opening the email by clicking on a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

The `mailto` protocol doesn't provide anything for that.